# Matlab - determine column wise the ordinal rank of values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, ordinal

I have following mxn matrix:

```
X = [-0.0061   -0.0108   -0.0098;
    0.0092    0.0237    0.0114;
   -0.0026   -0.0082    0.0035;
   -0.0033    0.0257   -0.0106]
```

What i want to do is to assign the ordinal rank within each column, i.e. to get following matrix Y.

```
Y = [1  1   2;
     4  3   4;
     3  2   3;
     2  4   1]
```

I tried it with [~,~,ranking] = unique(X) but unfortunately there it considers all matrix elements and ranks them ordinally and does not do the job column wise. Furthermore it puts the ranks in a column vector and not in the shape of upper Y matrix.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sort.html). Thanks to @beaker for the correction (see comments below);

```
[~, result] = sort(X, 1);
[~, result] = sort(result, 1);
```

Comment: thanks that one solves the problem! thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? The last column in the example doesn't match.

Comment: I think in order to match the results of the example you need to sort again: `[~, result2] = sort(result, 1);`

Comment: @beaker Oh, I see. I understood the question incorrectly then

Comment: @rookieMI Please see correction, with thanks to beaker